# Java arrays in classes and methods

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I'm new to Java and got totally stuck in arrays in classes. Have been trying to find out the answer to set and get method when working with arrays, unfortunately couldn't get my head around where the problem actually was. 
Would highly appreciate is someone please could help to get it figured out.
Here is my code:

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;
        public Animal(String name) {
            this.name = name;
         } //end of constructor

        public String getName(int i) {
            return this.name[i];
         } //end of getName

        public void setName(String name[]) {
            this.name = new String[] {"Tom", "Jerry"};
        } //end of setName

} //end of class Animal
```

I'm working in NetBeans and it highlights two error messages:
 - under get method: "an array required, but String found"
 - under set method: "incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String"

Can someone please explain what the error is? Seems it's quite simple but slipping sneaking away from my mind.

Many thanks

Comment: There is no array anywhere in your code, but for some reason you think there is. `String` and `String[]` are two totally different objects.

Comment: `String name`. Look at this closer. Then `this.name[i];`, and then `this.name = new String[] {"Tom", "Jerry"};`.

Comment: The reason I dislike the syntax `String name[]` instead of `String[] name`, is that it can cause confusion. Perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201610301501009189343).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have declared the variable to be a string:

```
private String name;
```

and you initialize it with a string:

```
public Animal(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} //end of constructor
```

later you attempt to put a string array into it:

```
this.name = new String[] {"Tom", "Jerry"};
```

and you try to access it as a string array:

```
return this.name[i];
```

String arrays are not the same thing as a string.  Declare the variable correctly and the program will run better.

```
private String[] name;
```

and you need to initialize it with an array.

```
public Animal(String initialName) {
    this.name = new String[1];
    this.name[0] = initialName;
} //end of constructor
```

Also, don't use the same identifier for a parameter that you use for a data member.  Too confusing.

Comment: If he declares it as an array, then his constructor won't make sense. I don't think the issue is a typographical error, but understanding of arrays.

Comment: Why do you insist of changing `name` to an array? What sense does it make to have an array of String for a name of an animal? Do you think that OP wants to support nick names? Unlikely.

Comment: I think they are doing an exercise in learning how String arrays work.  The last method shows two names: Tom and Jerry.  The get name has an index parameter.  I think the class is half-way converted from an animal with one name, to an animal with multiple names.  Agree, you might prefer to have an array of Animals, each with one name, but the question was not about that.

Comment: *"don't use the same identifier for a parameter that you use for a data member"* - I disagree. There is no confusion with the `this` keyword - and it stops you from creating an abundance of identifiers (which actually might cause confusion).

Comment: thanks @AgilePro! think I got it! an array of strings in constructor was unnecessary.Your last bit of code made perfect sense to me.So, I re-wrote it that way:
'public class Animal {'
     'private String name;'
     'public String getName() {'
        'return this.name;'
      '}'
      'public void setName(inti) {'
         'String[] myNames = new String[] {"Tom", "Jerry"};'
         'this.name = myNames[I];'
       '}'

'public static void main(String[] args) {'
    'Animal cat1 = new Animal();'
    'cat1.setName(0);'
    'System.out.println(cat1.getName());'
'}'
output: Tom

Comment: @Gendarme there is no cost to having more unique identifiers.  There IS a large cost to overloading the same identifier to have the different meaning.  Giving a unique identifier to different things does not cause confusion.  Giving the same name to things that are different does cause confusion.  I realize this is not going to convince you of anything, but for everyone else reading this, I stand by my statement that it is good to give different names to different things .